# How to get real value after discount.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, education

Suppose my item real value is 100. and i have given discount 10 % to my customer. Now the changed value of item id 90.  If i set value 110 and give 10% discount then i got result 99. but i need result 100.

```
What value should i set of item to get 100 after discount?
```

Comment: You want $0.9X = 100$ with $X$ the value that the customer needs to pay.

Comment: i want my real value after giving discount to customer

Comment: Then I do not understand the question. You want to give a 10% discount to a customer. With the discount, the customer should pay 100. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: discount is just only dummy part to show. i implemented logic but not working properly. i just want to get my real value of item after giving discount

Comment: If the value of the item is $111.1111111111$ and you give a $10\%$ discount, then you sell it for $100$. The question is still not clear to me.

Comment: @Ritz , suppose you have a item and you want to get their real price after given discount, how can we got this

Comment: Let $X$ be the initial price and let $p$ be the discount factor. Then the new price $Y = X \cdot (1-p)$. For example, $X = 111.111111$ and $p = 0.1$ then we get $Y = 111.111111 \cdot (1 - 0.1) = 100$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $x$ is the nominal price and the discount is $d$, then for $p$ the price really paied, you have: $x(1-d)=p$ so $x=\dfrac{p}{1-d}$.

Comment: thnak you so much